# Is it possible to create alerting in Azure App Insight automatically by script or other ways?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

There are a lot of manual steps to create alert on App Insight. Hence, I would like to have the script to configure alerting to save reduce effort when I would like to deploy new or even update it in future

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, for example using an [ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) or [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep) template. Or you can leverage the [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to [create alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert?view=azure-cli-latest)

For Bicep/ARM the template format can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/alertrules?tabs=bicep). The nice thing about this approach is that you can deploy the alerts using a ci/cd pipeline, for example using Azure DevOps.

Here is an alert based on an Application Insights log search result:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "scheduledqueryrules_alert_exception_name": {
            "defaultValue": "alert-fexception",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "components_ai_prod_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/components/xxx",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "actiongroups_team_blue": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/xxx",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules",
            "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('scheduledqueryrules_alert_exception_name')]",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('scheduledqueryrules_alert_exception_name')]",
                "severity": 1,
                "enabled": true,
                "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
                "scopes": [
                    "[parameters('components_ai__externalid')]"
                ],
                "targetResourceTypes": [
                    "microsoft.insights/components"
                ],
                "windowSize": "PT5M",
                "criteria": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "query": "exceptions\n| extend requestId = tostring(customDimensions.SpanId)\n| join kind=leftouter (requests) on $left.requestId == $right.['id']\n| project timestamp, operation_Id, problemId, cloud_RoleName, url, outerMessage, application_Version\n",
                            "timeAggregation": "Count",
                            "dimensions": [],
                            "operator": "GreaterThan",
                            "threshold": 0,
                            "failingPeriods": {
                                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "autoMitigate": false,
                "actions": {
                    "actionGroups": [
                        "[parameters('actiongroups_team_blue')]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```